# WordPress RSS feed with tag display

Tags: php, wordpress

I have just fresh WordPress installed. I am going to post a blog, I have created a category called "Client care" and created tags name "news" also I post the blog

When I checked my RSS feed (name.com/feed), It'll display

[image]

Can anyone please tell me, how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

use this code for showing tags

```
$tags = get_the_tags( get_the_ID() );
foreach($tags as $tag){
         echo '<p>'.$tag->name.'</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, where do I need to add? function.php?

Comment: no, where you want to show your tags there you can write this code.

Comment: I need to display only RSS feed with tag. which file need to update php code

Comment: where you want to display RSS feed with tag ?

Comment: @user2117713 if your problem has been solved, please don't forget to tick my answer as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

At Essence.com, we use this

```
<topics><![CDATA[<?php echo implode(', ', wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'article_tags', array('fields' => 'names'))); ?>]]></topics>
```

in a custom RSS feed template.
It displays the **tags** with links separated by ",".